# How to reject URLs whose query string begins with a hashtag?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Using mod_rewrite, how can I reject (by returning a 404) all URLs whose `QUERY_STRING` starts with a hashtag (`#`)? For example, these URLs are all examples of what I want to reject:

```
https://example.com/?#something
https://example.com/?#anything-else
https://example.com/?#i-don't-care-about-this-text
```

But if the string after the `?` begins with anything else, or if there's no query string at all, I want it to pass through.

I know the hashtag is a fragment identifier and that strings after the hashtag aren't something you can process with mod_rewrite, but I was expecting the hashtag itself to show up. So I've tried rules to match like these:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} #
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "#"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (#)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} -n
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

But none of these seem to catch it. Can you suggest a way to detect and reject URLs whose `QUERY_STRING` starts with a hashtag?

UPDATE: But if a request comes in for `https://example.com` (with no `?`) it should pass through.

Another idea I've tried is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/\?$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

What I'm trying to do here is say: if `REQUEST_URI` contains a `?` and if `QUERY_STRING` is empty, then redirect to 404. But it redirects everything (including URLs with non-empty query_strings) to 404.

Comment: fragment starting with `#` is not sent to web server so you cannot do this on server side

Comment: In that case, is there way to detect that the query string contains, essentially, nothing? In other words, if the "#something" isn't visible to the server, does that mean the server sees the query string as empty?

Comment: Then why doesn't `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} -n` or `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` catch it?

Comment: Indeed `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` should match an empty query string. Also note that `REQUEST_URI` can never contain a `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule to detect a `?` with no query string:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?\s
RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: I didn't think to regex the space. Works well. Though I'm still not sure why `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` doesn't work as expected in this case.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` will be true in both cases i.e. `example.com/` and `example.com/?#something`